# footer at bottom min-height

Tags: html, css

I have been working on my brothers web-site making some changes and I wanted to get the footer down.. (should have done this in the beginning..)

But it won't go down, I have tried every basic trick I know but for some reason it won't go down.. I think I missed something or did something wrong.

Can someone please help me! Because I have a case of tunnel vision and I don't see the mistake I made.

[Website](http://nickroeten.com/pages/links/)

If you need something I will post it!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Would you mind clarifying what you mean by "getting it down"? Do you mean sticking it to the bottom of the page?

Comment: Well yeah, and if there is content it moves down.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [Sticky Footer](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/sticky-footer/). Wrap your content in a `div` but exclude the footer script:

```
<div class="page-wrap">
   ALL Content

</div>

<footer>
  //footer script
</footer>
```

Then in your CSS set a height for your footer and use the same value as a negative margin for your wrapper and the `:after` selector:

```
html, body {
  height: 100%; //make sure you add this
}

.page-wrap {
  min-height: 100%;
  /* equal to footer height */
  margin-bottom: -100px; 
}

.page-wrap:after {
  height: 100px; 
  content: "";
  display: block;
}

footer {
  height: 100px; 
}
```

Comment: I like your solution. voted you up. :D can you explain further  what's the use of page-wrap:after?

Comment: Can you post what you did?

Comment: It worked but now it too far down haha! but it ill figure that out myself! thanks, first post i made a mistake

Comment: Well this is going to fix it to the very bottom, no matter how big the screen is

Comment: Yeah it did like it should, but now I got myself a scroll bar and I wanted it to stop at the edge of the screen. but you got me on the right track because I included the footer in the wrapper and I did not notice that.

Comment: @jmore009 nope I did nothing just red your css solution :D

Comment: @agentpx that was to Rob who had responded after you but has since removed the response